# Django | How to change nav class with change in URL?

Tags: html, css, django

I want to know the best approach to change the html class name according to the change in url.

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg fixed-top clean-navbar" >
    <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand logo" data-bs-hover-animate="jello"
            href="#">BootstrapNation</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler"
            data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><i style="color: white;" class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto mr-0">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">HOME <i
                            class="fas fa-home"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'snippets' %}">SNIPPETS <i class="fab fa-css3"
                            style="color: purple;"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'premium' %}">PREMIUM THEMES <i class="fab fa-product-hunt" style="color: green;"></i></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">LOGIN <i class="far fa-user"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

After every time use a nav-item, I want the class to include 'active', like if the url includes 'site.com/snippets' I want the class to say 'nav-item active' I think using request.get_full_path in if tag might be an approach, but that will make a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way for doing this would be:

```
 <li class="nav-item {% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'home' %}active{% endif %}">
```

Comment: oh I thought the if tag wouldn't work inside quotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it.

I think this is the simplest. When you render your view at your controller you can pass a var and print it when you need it:

```
return render(request, 'snippets.html', {'active-nav-item': 'home' }
```

Per nav-item check the var

```
<li class="nav-item {% if active-nav-item == 'home' %}active{% endif %}">
```